# Assembly numpy vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

How to add a numpy array A to elements of a numpy array B with indices given by an index array C?

Ideally, I can write:

```
A=np.zeros(4,float)
B=np.array([1,2,3,4])
C=np.array([1,2,1,3])
A[C] +=B
print A
```

output:
    [0, 4, 2, 4]

but it doesn't work since (according to documentation) A[C] is a copy. 
(I only wonder why it in fact works if indexes in C appears only once.)

I need to do it fast (for big arrays).

Comment: You don't use `B` in your calculation. Also, `np.()` uis not valid syntax. Please make your example code run in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your example was supposed to be

```
A = np.zeros(4, dtype=float)
B=np.array([1,2,3,4])
C=np.array([1,2,1,3])
A[C] += B
print A
```

If so, then instead of `+=`, you want [`numpy.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html). `add.at` does what `+=` does, but with repeated indices handled the way you want. Similar constructs work for other operators, e.g. `subtract.at` for `-=`.

```
numpy.add.at(A, C, B)
```